# Content Misplacement of side Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, tizen-web-app

i'm developing a app which has side navigation pane in which im getting a problem content misplacement
at some pages not in all

**Content Sliding below**

[image: Screenshot when sliding]

**Content proper**

[image: Screenshot which sliding is good]

**Code**
This is code for navigation

```
<label class='side-menu-overlay active' for="sideMenuHandler"></label>
<div class='side-menu'>
    <ul class="sideMenuList" style="-webkit-padding-start: 0px;">
        <li class="menuList" id="about" onclick="loadPage1('About Calendar')"><label class="textStyle"
             for="sideMenuHandler">About Calendar</label></li>
        <!-- <li class="menuList" id="email"><label class="textStyle"
            for="sideMenuHandler" onclick="loadPage2('Email us')">Email
                Us!</label></li>
        <li class="menuList" id="share"><label class="textStyle"
            for="sideMenuHandler" onclick="loadPage3('Share App')">Share
                the app!</a>
        </label></li>
        <li class="menuList" id="share"><label class="textStyle"
            for="sideMenuHandler" onclick="loadPage4('Rate')">Rate the
                app!</a>
        </label>
        </li> -->
        <li class="menuList" id="home" onclick="loadPage5('Calendar')"><label class="textStyle"
            for="sideMenuHandler">Home!</a>
        </label></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**Code for Main Part**

In this the "appcontent" part is wiped  by ajax and the aboutus content is placed

```
<input type="checkbox" class="side-menu-handler" id="sideMenuHandler">

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-bar">
        <label class="list-btn" id="menuButton" for="sideMenuHandler">
            <div class="menu-icon">
                <div class="bar"></div>
                <div class="bar"></div>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="appName">Calendar</div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="appContent">
        <div data-role="content" id="calendarPart">
            <div id="calendar">
                <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                    <!-- <h1>Single-page application</h1> -->
                </div>
                <!-- <p>This is a single page boilerplate template that you can copy
                to build your first Tizen Web UI Framework page.</p> -->
                <iframe style="width:75px;height:43px; border:none;position: absolute;top:85px;right:0;" src="http://dev.skyle.co/zen/a.html"></iframe>
                <div class="tabs">
                    <ul class="tab-links">
                        <li id="2013Year" class="active"><a href="#tab1">2013</a></li>
                        <li id="2014Year"><a href="">2014</a></li>
                        <li id="2015Year"><a href="">2015</a></li>
                        <!-- <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li> -->
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content"
                        style="width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 49px; height: 352px;">
                        <div id="tab1" class="tab active" id="lyear">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="g4">
                                        <div id="eventCalendarInline"
                                            style="position: absolute; left: 71px; top: 81px;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for About us Page

```
<div data-role="content" id="aboutPart">
<div>
    <h2>About:</h2>
    <p
        style="text-align: justify; font-size: medium; font-family: Source Sans Pro; padding-left: 17px; padding-right: 17px;">
        This app informs about the holidays and festivals in India. Festivals
        in India carry important message and plays important role in
        symbolizing the tradition and culture of India. This App provides
        list of major Indian festivals grouped by months. This App includes
        festivals and dates for 2013, 2014,2015 and 2016 (i.e. Previous year,
        Current year and Upcoming two years). Users can plan their holidays
        by using this app.</p>
    <h2>Features:</h2>
    <ul style="font-size: initial; font-family: Source Sans Pro; width: 83%;">
        <li>Monthly calendar view with all Indian festival, dates of
            holidays are highlighted.</li>
        <li>The festivals are in list view on the bottom half of the
            page, upon scrolling calendar goes up and festival list is shown in
            full page.</li>
        <li>Use navigation button to change the month. Traverse between
            months to view festivals.</li>
        <li>Menu is customized so that it can meet user expectations and
            this app is user friendly.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Kindly give some hint to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you custimizing the framework css or adding your own styles?

Comment: I'm adding my own styles

Comment: So many things can be wrong here. Please add you CSS to the question as well. The proper layout is on a different page of the same application or just a design preview?

Answer (score 0):

In **Code This is code for navigation** you have two tags `</label></li>` missing starting points (just before `<li class="menuList" id="home">`).
Also in the same part in `<li class="menuList" id="share">` an superfluous `</a>` closing tag exists.

In the **Code for About us Page** you are missing an end `</div>` tag.

Please recheck your code with those fixes, if this won't solve your problem I will try to help you further.

Comment: I checked my code. Every `label` and `div` tags are closed, but the problem still persists

Comment: @qwertymaster ok, please copy fixed HTML into you question.

Are you using Tizen SDK 2.3?